# MongoDB Record return field

Tags: mongodb, scala, lift

I insert a Record into a MongoDB

```
var test = Entry.createRecord
.name("Williams")
.nr("1")
.save
```

I query these via:

```
val qry = QueryBuilder.start("name").is("Williams").get
var my = test.findAll(qry)
println(my)
```

This Query returns the whole document. How can I query the name only?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the scala driver you mention but MongoDB natively supports a "projection" parameter which is an object listing all of the properties you'd like to return in the document. Take a look at how the following would be translated to your QueryBuilder syntax.

```
// Node.js syntax
var query = {name: 'Williams'}; // find all documents where name=Williams
var projection = {name: 1};     // only return the name property of each document
var cursor = db.test.find(query, projection);
```

Comment: using
  
 
    val qry = {"name" -> "Williams}
      val pro = {"name" -> 1}
      var my = test.findAll(qry, pro)
      println(my)

results in many many printlns of the document.


using
 

    val qry = QueryBuilder.start("name").is("Williams").get
          val pro = {"name" -> 1}
          var my = test.findAll(qry, pro)
          println(my)


results in an error (overloaded method value findAll with alternatives: ....)